# TYPO3 fileadmin directory shows all files of all pages in browser

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I do expirience the following problem.

I do have a TYPO3 v7.6 CMS with multiple websites.

The problem is, that all files are visible in fileadmin if written in URL

For example PDF File with link

www.webpage-one.com/fileadmin/webpage-one/documents/pdffile

will be opened in browser if you type another URL of a webpage inside the same TYPO3 Instance.

www.webpage-two.com/fileadmin/webpage-two/documents/pdffile

Anyone with expirience on the matter?
Cheers

Comment: maybe you can take a look at the extension EXT:secure_downloads https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/secure_downloads

Comment: Are you sure, @RiccardoDeContardi, EXT:secure_downloads takes into account domains?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know :(

Comment: No, secure_downloads doesn't take into account domains.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache (or another webserver that supports .htaccess and mod_rewrite) you can add a .htaccess file to the different directories in fileadmin with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !webpage-one.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

This will make this directory only accessible from domains containing webpage-one.com. Other domains will get a 403 Forbidden error.

If it should only work for www.webpage-one.com (so not without www), you should change the `RewriteCond` line to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.webpage-one.com$ [NC]
```

If it should work both with and without www, but not on other subdomains, you should use 2 `RewriteCond` lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webpage-one.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.webpage-one.com$ [NC]
```